# How do I push a pipeline variable to an azure repo?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an Azure pipeline that runs a Python script. This script makes an API call that returns a json. Here are the last few lines of the script:

```py
r = s.get(api_get_dashboard_by_uid + targetDashboardUid)

# set name of the variable
name = 'myJson'
# set value of the variable
value = r.json()

print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable={name};]{value}')
```

my pipeline's yaml file looks like this:

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/myTestPythonFile.py'

- bash: echo $(myJson)
```

the last line prints out the json, but I'm interested in storing it (indefinitely). I believe pushing it to an azure repo is an option, but I just can't make sense of the documentation / SO questions. Could anyone tell me what I need to replace `- bash: echo $(myJson)` with for my json to be stored in my project's repo? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output the json value into a **`.json`** file, and then push this file into the git repository using related git CLI.

In the Python script.

```
. . .
value = r.json()


# Serializing json
json_object = json.loads(value)
json_formatted_str = json.dumps(json_object, indent=2)

# Writing to myJson.json
with open("myJson.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_formatted_str)
```

In the pipeline, use the bash task to push the json file to Azure Git repos.

```yaml
steps:
- bash: |
   git config --global user.name {username}
   git config --global user.email {email}
   
   git add myJson.json
   git commit -m "Add file myJson.json"
   git push
  displayName: 'Push json file to repo'
```

Comment: Hello @Bright, thank you for your answer. It put me on the right track and I was able to push my file after some more fiddling. However, I am now stuck later on in the process, so I created a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77584488/azure-pipeline-cant-push-a-file-to-an-already-existing-azure-repo-branch can you please take a look? Thank you so much.

Comment: @VincentTep, I have posted an answer to your follow-up question. Check and try the steps shared in my answer.