# Azure pipeline - can't find Python script although it is in the same directory as the yml file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to get my pipeline to run a Python script. The script is in the same directory as the yml file, so I think this is the way to do it:

```yaml
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/myTestPythonFile.py'
```

The `yml` file and the python file are in the same folder

[image]

However, upon running the pipeline, I run into the following error: `##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory`

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: may i know if there's any update? Please follow my reply for a check, you can list the files as suggested for confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your error with your yaml.

[image]

The command `git checkout -b DIN_grafana_json_archives --track origin/DIN_grafana_json_archives` will **create a new local branch** `DIN_grafana_json_archives` and **switch to it**, it's tracking the remote branch. You can check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002239/difference-between-git-checkout-track-origin-branch-and-git-checkout-b-branch) for the command behavior details.

**After the command, the working directory content is from the new
branch, not the self branch**. And in your new branch, there is no target python file, which will cause the error.

In addition, to make sure the directory content, you can add bash task to list the files in the working directory before `pythonscript` task for a check.

```
- bash: |
   find . -type f
  displayName: checkout file list

- task: PythonScript@0
....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @wade zhou for your help. The python script is now found and runs successfully. However I've run into another git-related issue that I've desribed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77627083/azure-devops-untracked-file-preventing-newer-version-of-the-file-from-being-pu can you please take a look? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this step does not rewrite your folder content?

[image]

Comment: Hi! All files within the directory remain the same before/after the pipeline has run (and failed). This particular stage does not fail, so I don't think it rewrites anything. Here's the log for this stage: `
`git checkout -b DIN_grafana_json_archives --track origin/DIN_grafana_json_archives
= ... =
/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/72e190aa-537b-4daa-9916-51a79f6068b2.sh
Previous HEAD position was 331a926 Updated 23 11 24 myTestPipeline.yml
Switched to a new branch 'DIN_grafana_json_archives'
branch 'DIN_grafana_json_archives' set up to track 'origin/DIN_grafana_json_archives'.
`