# Azure Devops - untracked file preventing newer version of the file from being pushed

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My goal is to run a DevOps pipeline (in my repo's `main` branch) that does the following:

- run a Python script (in my repo's `main` branch) that returns a json called `myJson.json`
- push `myJson.json` to another branch in the same repo called `DIN_grafana_json_archives`.
- I would like to be able to run the exact same script periodically, so that an updated version of myJson.json is pushed to `DIN_grafana_json_archives` every time the script runs. That would allow me to keep an archive of the different versions of the json.

***Initial situation***

This is my `main` branch:
[image]

`23 11 24 myTestPipeline.yml` is my pipeline.

`myTestPythonFile.py` is the script called within the pipeline.

The `DIN_grafana_json_archives` branch already exists and is empty.

Here is my pipeline:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
    # Check out source files and persist the Git Credentials for use in next steps.
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true

    # Generate a new 'myJson.json' file with the new content in the Python script. 
    - script: python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
      displayName: 'upgrade pip'
    - script: python3 -m pip install pandas
      displayName: 'install pandas'
    - script: python3 -m pip install requests
      displayName: 'install requests'
    - script: python3 -m pip install datetime
      displayName: 'install datetime'
    
    - task: PythonScript@0
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'filePath'
        scriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/myTestPythonFile.py'
    
    # Commit and push the updated 'myJson.json' file to remote 'DIN_grafana_json_archives' branch.
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Push updates to remote'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          git config --global user.name {myUsername}
          git config --global user.email {myUsername@company.com}
          git checkout DIN_grafana_json_archives
          git add myJson.json
          git commit -m "Update file myJson.json"
          git push
```

The script runs fine and `myJson.json` is successfully pushed to `DIN_grafana_json_archives`.

***Problem when I run the script a 2nd time***

Objective: I would like the script to push a new version of myJson.json (this version could potentially be identical to the previous one) to `DIN_grafana_json_archives`, even though it already contains (an older version of) this file.

Problem: the script fails at th last stage with this error message:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    myJson.json
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
[detached HEAD db4eeee] Update file myJson.json
 1 file changed, 285 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 myJson.json
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>

##[error]Bash exited with code '128'.
Finishing: Push updates to remote
```

If I navigate to the `DIN_grafana_json_archives` branch and delete `myJson.json`, the script runs fine.
What do I need to do for my script to be able to run multiple times? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Replacing

```
git checkout DIN_grafana_json_archives
```

with

```
git checkout -f DIN_grafana_json_archives
```

prevents the last step from failing. The logs for this step read:

```
Previous HEAD position was bdf49df Update 23 11 24 myTestPipeline.yml for Azure Pipelines
Switched to a new branch 'DIN_grafana_json_archives'
branch 'DIN_grafana_json_archives' set up to track 'origin/DIN_grafana_json_archives'.
On branch DIN_grafana_json_archives
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/DIN_grafana_json_archives'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Everything up-to-date
Finishing: Push updates to remote
```

However, no updated version of myJson.json is pushed to the target repo. Why is that? Why do the logs say "nothing to commit" even though the next lines are git add / commit / push ?

Comment: If the answers were helpful for you, please up-vote and accept them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking DIN_grafana_json_archives out which is causing the error you can just push directly on it using

```
git push origin HEAD:DIN_grafana_json_archives
```

Just leave out checkout step in your script and replace git push with this command.

Comment: Hi, doing this yields the following message: ` ! [rejected]        HEAD -> DIN_grafana_json_archives (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/[...]'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you want to integrate the remote changes, use 'git pull'
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this because `checkout` command works with the *commit* at the time the pipeline was queued rather than the latest values in the branch. This enables the pipeline to be "re-run" deterministically from a specific point in time. Under the hood, git refers to this scenario is as a [*detached head*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem--detachltcommitgt).

If you look at the output from the `checkout` command, you'll see something like this:

[image: snippet from pipeline]

Keep in mind that the branch may have changed from the time that the pipeline was originally queued, so you may need to fetch the latest changes to prevent your push from being rejected. If your pipeline runs automatically as a batched trigger, this is less likely to occur as you should always have the latest.

```bash
git fetch
git checkout $branch
git pull
```

The second thing to consider is you should checkout and update *before* you modify the contents of the repository as git will prevent you from switching with untracked changes. As you discovered, this is why you had to add the `--force` parameter.

Lastly, as an optimization, you should commit and push only if there are modifications. For example, suppose your script produces a result that is identical to the current copy of your file.

Assuming you are only modifying existing files, the following should work:

```bash
changes=$(git ls-files --modified --deleted)

if [ -n "$changes" ]; then
  # stage and add all changes
  git commit --all -m"Updated from pipeline [skip ci]"
  git push
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, no updated version of myJson.json is pushed to the target
> repo. Why is that? Why do the logs say "nothing to commit" even though
> the next lines are git add / commit / push ?

When you check out with `git checkout -f DIN_grafana_json_archives`, it will replace the new `myJson.json` file with the old one in the branch. This is why it says "nothing to commit".

### Workaround 1

You can copy the file to rename it with a new unique name. Then you can push the file to the branch without this problem.

My yaml sample:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
    # Check out source files and persist the Git Credentials for use in next steps.
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true

    # Just to create a new myJson.json file.
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'Write-Output "Backups time $(Get-Date)" >>myJson.json'

    # Copy to backup the json file with a new filename.
    # Commit and push the updated the new filename json file to remote 'DIN_grafana_json_archives' branch.
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Push updates to remote'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          cp myJson.json $(Build.BuildNumber)myJson.json
          git config --global user.name {myUsername}
          git config --global user.email {myUsername@company.com}
          git fetch
          git checkout DIN_grafana_json_archives 
          git add $(Build.BuildNumber)myJson.json
          git commit -m "Upload $(Build.BuildNumber)myJson.json for BuildId $(Build.BuildId)"
          git push
```

Result:

[image]

### Workaround 2

Copy to backup the json file with a new filename. After check out the branch, delete the old json file and rename back the new json file.
Then commit and push the updated the json file to remote 'DIN_grafana_json_archives' branch.

Yaml：

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
    # Check out source files and persist the Git Credentials for use in next steps.
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true

    # Just to create a new myJson.json file.
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'Write-Output "Backups time $(Get-Date)" >>myJson.json'

    # Copy to backup the json file with a new name.
    # After check out the branch, delete the old json file and rename back the new json file. 
    # Then commit and push the updated the json file to remote 'DIN_grafana_json_archives' branch.
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Push updates to remote'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          cp myJson.json $(Build.BuildNumber)myJson.json
          git config --global user.name {myUsername}
          git config --global user.email {myUsername@company.com}
          git fetch
          git checkout DIN_grafana_json_archives -f
          rm myJson.json
          cp  $(Build.BuildNumber)myJson.json myJson.json
          git add myJson.json
          git commit -m "$(Build.BuildNumber) Upload myJson.json "
          git push
```

Result:

[image]